# Subclassing initialize method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a class `Foo` that implements an `+(void)initialize` method.  I also have a class that's a subclass of `Foo`.  When I instantiate the subclass, the `initialize` method also gets called on `Foo` which I don't want.  How do I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you just don't do `self = [super init]` in the subclass `init` method?

Comment: I think he is talking about the class `initialize` method, but if he is really referring to `init`, then that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by not implementing initialize and just calling a setup method instead

Comment: Costique's answer is better, and also the recommended way by Apple. Calling a setup method only once can be surprisingly difficult in the presence of multiple threads, and initialize is made for that purpose.

Comment: Fishinear, bbum says otherwise and is usually right (http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/)

Answer (score 7):

In your scenario (when there are subclasses involved) you should check the class to which the `initialize` method is sent:

```
+ (void) initialize
{
    if ( self == [MyClass class] )
    {
        // Do something here only once
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement `+ (void)initialize` in your subclass as well.  Usually people call `[super initialize]`, but you'll want to skip that step.  An empty method will prevent `Foo`'s from being called.

**EDIT** The superclasses `initialize` method is always called.  It can't and shouldn't be prevented by subclassing, because technically the superclass is initialized too and could be used independently.

Comment: I implement initialize in BOTH my subclass and superclass.  According to the apple docs, the superclass's initialize will always get called before any subclasses.  Is there anyway to prevent that

Comment: Huh.  I tested it out and see the same thing.  I think I'm changing my answer.  What is Foo's `initialize` method doing that you must prevent?

Comment: It alloc-inits an object that listens for and acts on notifications in a way different to how its subclass does it.  I've solved it by not implementing initialize and just calling a setup method instead.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution.. It probably didn't belong in `initialize` in the first place.  Please add your answer and accept it when allowed.