# How does an Objective C subclass initialize method calls the superclass's initialize method

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass, superclass

While reading the 'objective c guide' from Apple's dev site, i got some question marks. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913798/subclassing-initialize-method-in-objective-c) I already know that both sub and superclass 'initialize' methods get called. My question is; why does this happen? I know from that post also that the initialize is always called, but is that even true when I never use the superclass itself, and only the subclass?

A slight related question which came to mind on this topic:

- Does a subclass 'contain' it's superclass, together with some new methods/variables, or
- is everything copied from the superclass into the subclass?

In the first case i would understand that the initialize method would be sent to the 'contained' superclasses within the subclass, in the second option, I'd expect the subclass's initialize method to explicitely call [super initialize], which it doesn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+initialize` call is special and is explicitly called for every class. This is done outside of the normal inheritance chain you would be used to seeing. `+initialize` will be called on every class, subclass and category (yes, categories get their own initialize) the first time they're accessed.